Reading and getting sets of data from a file with numbers and words
I am trying to get the city, state, and then a number indicating area from a file. Then I need to do the same with another file with the same cities and states with a number indicating population and make a file in the same format for the population density. I don't understand how I should go about doing this
I am new to py and don't have a lot of coding experience so this is what I have so far
here is the population txt file:
Calico, California         12
Rhyolite, Nevada           3
Goldfield, Arizona         30
St. Elmo, Colorado         6
Terlingua, Texas           100
Virginia City, Montana     10
Nevada City, Montana       12
Bodie, California          45
Cahawba, Alabama           22
Kennecott, Alaska          2
Bannack, Montana           233
South Pass City, Wyoming   43
Centralia, Pennsylvania    6
Thurmond, West Virginia    55
Glenrio, Texas             1
Glenrio, New Mexico        1
Bulowville, Florida        54

here is the area txt file:
Calico, California         2
Rhyolite, Nevada           3
Goldfield, Arizona         12
St. Elmo, Colorado         4
Terlingua, Texas           10
Virginia City, Montana     15
Nevada City, Montana       6
Bodie, California          100
Cahawba, Alabama           20
Kennecott, Alaska          300
Bannack, Montana           23
South Pass City, Wyoming   3
Centralia, Pennsylvania    6
Thurmond, West Virginia    50
Glenrio, Texas             1
Glenrio, New Mexico        1
Bulowville, Florida        60

I know I need to do something along the lines of:
OpenFile = open( Population.txt', 'r')

for EachLine in OpenFile:
    Split = EachLine.strip.split("   ")
    #some sort of append to a list but with the first part of split in one list and the number
    # nested in that  list

OpenFile.close()


Maybe a dictionary would fit your needs. The keys can be the city and state, and the values can be the corresponding area or population.

well actually if you just need population density txt, that won't even be necessary to make a dictionary, given that both txt files have the same cities in the same order.

If you know the two txt files will have the same exact lines in the same order:
from pathlib import Path

population_path = Path('population.txt')
area_path = Path('area.txt')
output_path = Path('density.txt')
with open(population_path, 'r') as pop_file, open(area_path, 'r') as area_file, open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
  for pop_line, area_line in zip(pop_file, area_file):
    city_state_pop, population = pop_line.rsplit(' ', 1)
    city_state_area, area = area_line.rsplit(' ', 1)
    density = int(population) / int(area)
    output_file.write(f"{city_state_pop} {density:.2f}\n")

Output density.txt:
Calico, California         6.00
Rhyolite, Nevada           1.00
Goldfield, Arizona         2.50
St. Elmo, Colorado         1.50
Terlingua, Texas           10.00
Virginia City, Montana     0.67
Nevada City, Montana       2.00
Bodie, California          0.45
Cahawba, Alabama           1.10
Kennecott, Alaska          0.01
Bannack, Montana           10.13
South Pass City, Wyoming   14.33
Centralia, Pennsylvania    1.00
Thurmond, West Virginia    1.10
Glenrio, Texas             1.00
Glenrio, New Mexico        1.00
Bulowville, Florida        0.90

Alternatively, if you cannot guarantee the same order in the two txt files, consider breaking down your task into steps and creating helper functions for each step:
from pathlib import Path


def read_data(filename: Path) -> dict[str, int]:
  """Reads data from a given filename and parses it into a dictionary.
  
  Expected file only has lines with 'City, State' followed by whitespace and a integer.

  Args:
    filename (Path): The path to the file to read.

  Returns:
    A dictionary where keys are 'City, State' and values are integers.
  """
  data = {}
  with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
      line = line.strip()
      if line:
        parts = line.rsplit(' ', 1)
        name = parts[0].strip()
        number = int(parts[1])
        data[name] = number
  return data


def calculate_density(population_data: dict[str, int],
                      area_data: dict[str, int]) -> dict[str, float]:
  """Calculates the population density by dividing the population by the area.

  Args:
    population_data: A dictionary of populations keyed by 'City, State'.
    area_data: A dictionary of areas keyed by 'City, State'.

  Returns:
    A dictionary of population densities keyed by 'City, State'.
  """
  return {
    city_state: population / area_data[city_state]
    for city_state, population in population_data.items()
    if city_state in area_data
  }


def write_data(filename: Path, data: dict[str, float]) -> None:
  """Writes data dict to a file after sorting, with each key-value pair on a new line.

  Args:
    filename: The path to the file where data will be written.
    data: The data to write, where each key-value pair is a line.
  """
  longest_key_length = max(len(key) for key in data)
  format_string = f"{{:<{longest_key_length}}} {{:>10}}\n"
  with open(filename, 'w') as file:
      for key, value in sorted(data.items()):
          # Right-align the value in a 10-character wide field.
          file.write(format_string.format(key, f"{value:.2f}"))

def main() -> None:
  """Entry point of script."""
  write_data(filename=Path('density.txt'),
             data=calculate_density(
                 population_data=read_data(Path('population.txt')),
                 area_data=read_data(Path('area.txt')),
             ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

Output density.txt:
Bannack, Montana              10.13
Bodie, California              0.45
Bulowville, Florida            0.90
Cahawba, Alabama               1.10
Calico, California             6.00
Centralia, Pennsylvania        1.00
Glenrio, New Mexico            1.00
Glenrio, Texas                 1.00
Goldfield, Arizona             2.50
Kennecott, Alaska              0.01
Nevada City, Montana           2.00
Rhyolite, Nevada               1.00
South Pass City, Wyoming      14.33
St. Elmo, Colorado             1.50
Terlingua, Texas              10.00
Thurmond, West Virginia        1.10
Virginia City, Montana         0.67


You can try the following code:
import re

with open("area.txt", "r") as a, open("population.txt", "r") as p, open("population_density.txt", "w") as d:
    areas = a.read().splitlines()
    populations = p.read().splitlines()
    for area, population in zip(areas, populations):
        city = re.search(r"^[^,]+, [A-Za-z]+ ([A-Za-z]+)?", area)[0]
        area = int(re.search(r"\d+", area)[0])
        population = int(re.search(r"\d+", population)[0])
        d.write(f"{city:<27}{population/area:.3f}\n")

population_density.txt:
Calico, California         6.000
Rhyolite, Nevada           1.000
Goldfield, Arizona         2.500
St. Elmo, Colorado         1.500
Terlingua, Texas           10.000
Virginia City, Montana     0.667
Nevada City, Montana       2.000
Bodie, California          0.450
Cahawba, Alabama           1.100
Kennecott, Alaska          0.007
Bannack, Montana           10.130
South Pass City, Wyoming   14.333
Centralia, Pennsylvania    1.000
Thurmond, West Virginia    1.100
Glenrio, Texas             1.000
Glenrio, New Mexico        1.000
Bulowville, Florida        0.900

